# Crystal Report Viewer control isn't loading the images inside the report

Tags: asp.net, image, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.Net (.Net 2.0) application that creates Crystal Reports (version 11.5) and shows them with CrystalReportViewer control. For some reason the control isn't showing the logo image in the header of the report. It renders the following html

```
<img width="320" height="76" alt="Imagem" src="CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_e47fba99-96fc-471b-ab11-06fd2212bbdd.png" border="0"/>
```

I already included the aspnet_client folder in my Virtual Directory in IIS.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out.

For some reason the CrystalImageHandler wasn't defined in the web.config.

Just added the following line to the HttpHandler section and it worked. (The *Version* and *PublicKeyToken* values will be diferent for other versions of Crystal Reports)

```
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Goes in `httpHandlers`.

Found it configured by default for `CR2008` aka `XII`