# Crystal Reports Images not loading in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports in a Webform inside of an MVC application. Images in the reports are not being displayed, however, on both the ASP.NET Development Server and IIS 7 (on Win7x64).

I know from a number of other questions similar to this that the CrystalImageHandler HTTP Handler is responsible for rendering the image, but I've tried all of the usual solutions to no avail.

So far, I have

1. Added the following to my `appSettings` (via http://www.mail-archive.com/bdotnet@groups.msn.com/msg26882.html)

   `<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />`

   `<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />`

   `<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />`
2. Added the following httpHandler to `system.web/httpHandlers` (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253682/crystal-report-viewer-control-isnt-loading-the-images-inside-the-report)

   `<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>`
3. Added the following to my Global.asax.cs (via [Crystal Reports Images and ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006011/crystal-reports-images-and-asp-net-mvc))
   `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");`

and
`routes.IgnoreRoute("CrystalImageHandler.aspx");`

Any ideas as to why the images still 404?

Comment: @bummi, this question predates the 'original' by 2 years, how is this the duplicate?

Comment: While I agree that the top-voted answer on the other question seems more thorough, I have to say that this question is better. It's very well researched, and shows the steps taken to attempt to arrive at a solution using other potential answers from the net. Please don't penalize me for the work I've taken to make this an SO-worthy question.

Comment: Hi @bummi, this is clearly not the appropriate channel for this discussion, how can we continue it?

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem. This helped me.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*(CrystalImageHandler).*" });
```

Comment: I have added above in routeConfig it doesn't work then i have added crystal report handler in web.config file `<add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" 
           type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web,  Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />` 
now its working perfect.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the multitude of ways this can supposedly be made to work. None did. So I eventually settled on cheating:

```
public class CrystalImageHandlerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Reports/CrystalImageHandler.aspx

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("");
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var handler = new CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler();
        var app = (HttpApplication)filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.GetService(typeof(HttpApplication));
        if (app == null) return;

        handler.ProcessRequest(app.Context);

    }
}
```

I added a route to this controller matching what Crystal expects (./CrystalImageHandler.aspx) and used this controller to invoke the handler when the action is executed. Not pretty, but functional.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it to `system.webServer/handlers`? That should fix it on IIS7 but it is strange it doesn't work on the development server w/o that.

Comment: I actually did add it to the IIS7 application web.config, to no avail.. I suspect that if it won't work on the dev. server it won't work on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in RouteConfig.cs file

routes.IgnoreRoute("Reports/{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

Note 
"Reports" is the folder name which contains the aspx file of report viewer 
change this folder name as per your application